# Use of traditional copper sauteuse pans

Tags: utensils, traditional

I have been given a set of very thick and heavy tinned copper sauteuse pans, 5 in all, ranging from large down to small. I have no idea what they are used for. They don't come with lids but I have copper lids with gunmetal handles that came with a set of Leon Jaeggi saucepans that were a wedding present forty years ago.

If anyone has a definitive answer for their use in an old fashioned professional kitchen I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

A sauteuse pan is a very versatile pan. If you have no lid, it's a great pan for sautéing and browning. With a thin layer of oil you can cook vegetables, scallops, latkes, etc. If you have lids that fit you can braise in these. You can also use to cook pasta, stews, etc. Copper is good conductor, so these should heat evenly. I also sometimes use a pan like this for pâte à choux. They sound like really nice pans.

Comment: Latkes, there's a thought! I have pans well suited to all those things. I think in the professional kitchen they came from the chefs used to shake the contents around a lot.